# How to access data from has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I've got two models: Patient and Provider joined through a table Chart.

I used the association "has_many :through" [rather than "has_and_belongs_to_many"] because i need to have another column in the Chart table [called patient_mrn]

What I'm trying to do is to show a given patient and all its associated providers [each with its name and specific patient_mrn].

I do this by grabbing all the charts that contain a given patient_ID. Then i can easily display the patient_mrn from each chart using

```
<%= chart.patient_mrn %>
```

But when i try to reach through the chart to the provider model to grab the provider name using

```
<%= chart.provider.provider_name %>
```

I get an 'undefined method `provider_name' for nil:NilClass' error.

What am I doing wrong here?   Here is more detail from the code:

The Patient model has:

```
has_many :charts
has_many :providers, :through => :charts
```

The Provider model has:

```
has_many :charts 
has_many :patients, :through => :charts
```

and the Chart model has:

```
belongs_to :patient
belongs_to :provider
```

Then in my show action in the patient controller i have:

```
@patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
@charts = Chart.where(:patient_id => @patient.id)
```

And in my show view for patient i have:

```
<h2>Listing Providers</h2>

 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Patient mrn</th>
    <th>Provider</th>
  </tr>

<% @charts.each do |chart| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= chart.patient_mrn %></td>
    <td><%= chart.provider.provider_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: It is because you are getting `chart.provider` as `nil`.

Comment: Sorry Shweta, i'm a n00b and don't understand. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are getting `chart.provider` as `nil`.

In your `charts` table you might have rows with `null provider_id`

or

In your `providers` table there is no record(id) present with `provider_id` in `charts` table

**Try:**

```
<td><%= chart.provider.try(:provider_name) %></td>
```

[Calling try on nil always returns nil. It becomes specially helpful when navigating through associations that may return nil.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try)